# Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference problem in fortran

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to use fortran to calculate a value from a data.

```
program signifikansi
implicit none
integer :: N_energi, N_sudut, i, N
double precision,allocatable :: theta1(:), theta_lab1(:), dsig1(:), dsig_lab1(:), pol1(:), dpolxx1(:), dpolxz1(:), phase1(:), t1(:)
double precision,allocatable :: theta2(:), theta_lab2(:), dsig2(:), dsig_lab2(:), pol2(:), dpolxx2(:), dpolxz2(:), phase2(:), t2(:)   
double precision,allocatable :: signif(:) 
double precision :: signif_total,signif2

    write(*,*)"Masukkan jumlah energi"
    read(*,*)N_energi

    write(*,*)"Masukkan jumlah sudut pada setiap energi"
    read(*,*)N_sudut

N=N_sudut*N_energi

    write(*,*)"Total data adalah",N

open(unit=10, file='kminpobs.dat', status="old", action="read")
allocate(theta1(N))
allocate(theta_lab1(N))
allocate(dsig1(N))
allocate(dsig_lab1(N))
allocate(pol1(N))
allocate(dpolxx1(N))
allocate(dpolxz1(N))
allocate(phase1(N))
allocate(t1(N))

do i=1,N
read(10,*) theta1(i), theta_lab1(i), dsig1(i), dsig_lab1(i), pol1(i), dpolxx1(i), dpolxz1(i), phase1(i), t1(i)
end do
close(10)

open(unit=10, file='kminpnoscalar.dat', status="old", action="read")
allocate(theta2(N))
allocate(theta_lab2(N))
allocate(dsig2(N))
allocate(dsig_lab2(N))
allocate(pol2(N))
allocate(dpolxx2(N))
allocate(dpolxz2(N))
allocate(phase2(N))
allocate(t2(N))

do i=1,N
read(10,*) theta2(i), theta_lab2(i), dsig2(i), dsig_lab2(i), pol2(i), dpolxx2(i), dpolxz2(i), phase2(i), t2(i)
end do
close(10)

do i=1,N
signif(i) = (ABS(dsig2(i)-dsig1(i)))/dsig1(i)
end do

signif_total = SUM(signif)

signif2 = signif_total/N

write(*,*)"Hasil signifikansi untuk partikel tersebut adalah",signif2

deallocate(theta1)
deallocate(theta_lab1)
deallocate(dsig1)
deallocate(dsig_lab1)
deallocate(pol1)
deallocate(dpolxx1)
deallocate(dpolxz1)
deallocate(phase1)
deallocate(t1)
deallocate(theta2)
deallocate(theta_lab2)
deallocate(dsig2)
deallocate(dsig_lab2)
deallocate(pol2)
deallocate(dpolxx2)
deallocate(dpolxz2)
deallocate(phase2)
deallocate(t2)

end program signifikansi
```

here is my code but all i get is an error massage like this

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F0C2BFC2777
#1  0x7F0C2BFC2D7E
#2  0x7F0C2BC1AD3F
#3  0x403034 in MAIN__ at signifikansi1.f90:?
Segmentation fault
```

The N_energi for the input is 39, and the N_sudut is 120.
I got the N value at the output but my code can not calculate further result.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.
My guessing is the array size i used is too big.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please also use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Whenever you are debugging, you should use the error checking and debugging flags in gfortran. Use `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all` and you will get much better info for you and also for us. Be aware that we cannot test your program without your input file. Please recompile your program with the flags I mentioned and update the error message by using [edit]. Also please show us the input file, if possible.

Comment: You haven't allocated signif. There may be other errors, but without an input file as VladimirF says we can't test it

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your code and loaded it into my Eclipse IDE, using the free GNU Fortran.

I have run Project - Build All. The way it compiles the code is to use flag -WAll which shows all warnings, and this is always a good idea. Your Fortran compiler may have a different set of flags to choose from.

```
13:26:49 **** Build of configuration Debug for project TestFortran2 ****
make all 
Building file: ../TestFortran2.f90
Invoking: GNU Fortran Compiler
gfortran -funderscoring -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "TestFortran2.o" "../TestFortran2.f90"
../TestFortran2.f90:52:0:

 signif(i) = (ABS(dsig2(i)-dsig1(i)))/dsig1(i)

Warning: 'signif.offset' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
../TestFortran2.f90:55:0:

 signif_total = SUM(signif)

Warning: 'signif.offset' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
../TestFortran2.f90:55:0: Warning: 'signif.dim[0].lbound' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
../TestFortran2.f90:55:0: Warning: 'signif.dim[0].ubound' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
Finished building: ../TestFortran2.f90

Building target: TestFortran2
Invoking: GNU Fortran Linker
gfortran  -o "TestFortran2"  ./TestFortran2.o   
Finished building target: TestFortran2


13:26:53 Build Finished. 0 errors, 4 warnings. (took 4s.364ms)
```

These are the lines which show warnings in the code editor, on lines 51 through 55:

```
do i=1,N 
    signif(i) = (ABS(dsig2(i)-dsig1(i)))/dsig1(i) 
end do

signif_total = SUM(signif)
```

As Ian Bush has already commented above, it looks like you haven't allocated the *signif* array. It seems to need to be of size *N*. So, I added it to the code, allocated at the end of the other allocations, and added it also to the list of deallocations.

I then cleaned the build, and rebuilt it all. Result is no errors or warnings.

As already noted, we cannot do more without an input file, but since N is, in your example, only of size 39 x 120 = 5,000 elements it is unlikely to cause a problem for allocations.

You can always check for the success of an allocation, using the Stat keyword:

```
Allocate(Array(Size),Stat=SuccessCode)
```

A couple of other things. It's worth getting a good IDE as this will make coding much easier. Also, when you code, it's not essential that you indent your code, but it does make it much easier to read it later.

Comment: The stat= argument iz less useful than it might seem to be. Linux would normally give you much more virtual memory, than there is memory available, and will only crash at the first attempt to use that memory.